# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText

Tags: java, android, java.lang.class

I'm getting the following Error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast
>   to android.widget.EditText at
>   com.example.bmicalculator.MainActivity.initializeApp(MainActivity.java.32)

#### Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private EditText heightIn;
private EditText weightIn;
private Button CalculateButton;
private double weight =0;
private double height =0;
private TextView BmiResult;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initializeApp();
    }

    private void initializeApp() {
        heightIn = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.HeightInput1);
        weightIn = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.WeightInput1);
        CalculateButton = (Button) findViewById (R.id.CalculateButton);
        BmiResult = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.BmiResult);

    }

    public void calculateBMI(View v) {
        weight = Double.parseDouble(weightIn.getText().toString());
        height = Double.parseDouble(heightIn.getText().toString());
        double bmi = (weight / (height * height));
        String result = String.format("%.2f", bmi);
        Log.d("MyActivity", result);
        BmiResult.setText(result, TextView.BufferType.NORMAL);
    }
}
```

#### XML File:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/HeightInput1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/HeightInput"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/InchesHint"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/WeightInput1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/WeightInput"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/PoundsHint"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/CalculateButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="calculateBMI"
    android:text="@string/CalculateButton" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/BmiResult"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.00"
    android:text="@string/BmiResult" />
```

Comment: Would really appreciate anybody's help!

Comment: Change your editTexts id as HeightInput1 and WeightInput1

Comment: Thank you so much, that stopped the program from crashing. Would you have any idea why my calculation is not working though?

Comment: You have to implement ButtonClickListener to perform your operation when u click on 'CalculateButton'

Comment: CalculateButton = (Button) findViewById (R.id.CalculateButton);
      CalculateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
     
    
     
 @Override 
  public void onClick(View v) {
    calculateBMI();
   
      }
     });
    }
    public void calculateBMI() {
    weight = Double.parseDouble(weightIn.getText().toString());
     height = Double.parseDouble(heightIn.getText().toString());
     double bmi = (weight / (height * height));
     String result = String.format("%.2f", bmi);
     Log.d("MyActivity", result);
     BmiResult.setText(result, TextView.BufferType.NORMAL);

Comment: i have added this onClickListener but it still does not work?

Answer (score 4):

Your `heightIn` is not `EditText` and you're trying to cast it as `EditText` so you got Error

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be
>   cast to android.widget.EditText at
>   com.example.bmicalculator.MainActivity.initializeApp(MainActivity.java.32)

so do as,

```
heightIn = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.HeightInput1);
weightIn = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.WeightInput1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/HeightInput1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/HeightInput"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/WeightInput1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/WeightInput"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

Via

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/HeightInput1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/HeightInput"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/WeightInput1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/WeightInput"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

**OR**

```
heightIn = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.HeightInput1);
weightIn = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.WeightInput1);
```

via

```
heightIn = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.HeightInput1);
weightIn = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.WeightInput1);
```

Comment: Hope this may help you!

Answer (score 2):

in java file

```
heightIn = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.HeightInput1);
```

and

in xml file

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/HeightInput1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/HeightInput"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

So change according to your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

1. There are two possibilities,  HeightInput1 id component should be Edit text not a text view
2. else In code change the Edit text to Text view whose id is HeightInput1

so change 
java code with this

```
    heightIn = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.HeightInput1);  
    weightIn = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.WeightInput1);
```

else change in xml file with this

```
  <EditText
   android:id="@+id/HeightInput1"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/HeightInput"
   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: is it ok now ,else do you think anything more can be done to this?

Comment: Yeah, that does look like a nice answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

In Xml file you are declare as TextView and you are trying to parse TextView to EditText that's why you are getting an Exception.

Change EditText Variable

```
private EditText heightIn;
private EditText weightIn;
```

To

```
private TextView heightIn;
private TextView weightIn;
```

And replace your initializeApp() function with:

```
private void initializeApp() {
    heightIn = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.HeightInput1);
    weightIn = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.WeightInput1);
    CalculateButton = (Button) findViewById (R.id.CalculateButton);
    BmiResult = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.BmiResult);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 heightIn = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.HeightInput1);
```

Here you mentioned heightIn  as EditTect and in your layout.xml it is as TextView,
instead of finding "HeightInput1" which is just your text to label, it should find the EditText

```
 heightIn = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.EditText1);
```

same with the weight input... good luck!